# Как выбрать несколько пользователей из таблицы

Tags: массивы, phpmyadmin, php, sql

Есть, например, массив с именами: `'ВАСЯ', 'КОЛЯ', 'ПЕТЯ'`. Как получить результат, где `login = эти именам`. То бишь в результате должно получиться так:

```
[0] => [ 'login' => ВАСЯ ],
[1] => [ 'login' => КОЛЯ ],
[2] => [ 'login' => ПЕТЯ ]
```

Получить из таблицы именно эти 3 строки по полю, сделав это все одним запросом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.

```
SELECT a, b, c, d FROM table_name WHERE login IN ('ВАСЯ', 'КОЛЯ', 'ПЕТЯ')
```